# Noun describing the property of being tricky to reason about

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an English word that would describe, for a concept, the property of being tricky to reason about. Something that does not fit naturally in the mind and causes us to reason incorrectly.

The closest I have come up with is "**inscrutability**" or perhaps "**abstrusity**". However, both convey the idea that the concept feels immediately opaque upon inspection. I would like a work that also works for describing concepts that may seem easy to reason about, but which end up being tricky.

Edit: some good suggestions already. I'm looking for something that doesn't necessarily *have* to be tricky, counterintuitive, or deceptive, but that *could*. The problem is that **abstrusity** seems to exclude concepts which may seem superficially simple. *Complexity* gets close, but it conflicts with another use of the work in the domain I am writing about (programming language theory).

Edit2: **equivocality** is a possibility, but too much emphasis is placed on ambiguity and it seems to exclude obscurity which can also be a source of confusion.

Comment: It is a *difficult* concept. It is a *complex* topic.

Comment: Perhaps you want “deceptive” or “not as straightforward as it seems”.  “Tricky” is also good and you’ve already used it in your title.

Comment: A *counterintuitive* concept?

Comment: Deceptive is doable: deceitfulness, but see edit.

Comment: A confusing concept ? "causing bewilderment; difficult to follow; puzzling" also "an alien concept" it's used for something that does not fit in a normal pattern of thought of someone  and therefore is tricky to think about.

Comment: convolutedness turns out to be a word (which I might recoil from).

Comment: A *foreign* concept would be hard to reason about since there can be no intuition to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, consider [intractable](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/intractable?s=t) which can mean not easily controlled or directed, e.g. an [intractable problem](http://www.umsl.edu/~siegelj/information_theory/classassignments/Lombardo/04_intractableproblems.html) is problem for which there is no straightforward and efficient solution.

Answer (score 3):

An **enigma** can be tricky to deal with. It can be a person, concept, or work. **Enigmatic** refers to the "problem."

A **deception** is some thing that is or can be purposefully *meant* to look like something it is not. An adjective like **deceptive** might work if you don't need a noun.

Simple looking situations can be **misleading** in that the solution might involve unseen, hidden, or not immediately apparent complexities.

Sometimes a solution is **not immediately apparent** (a construction). The worst problems are sometimes said to be **political**. Some problems are simply **deep** or **elusive**.

**Seeming** or **seemingly** can change smooth waters into precarious ones.

Answer (score 2):

**[perplexity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perplexity)** (noun)

> something that is confusing and difficult to understand

[also](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perplexity)

> The state of being intricate or complicated

Another possibility that I think is a stretch, but may contain the nature of subtle complexity you seem to be looking for is

**[texture](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/texture)**

This application of the word was inspired by the answers and comments to [this other question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285108/what-does-be-textured-and-fraught-mean).

> "Textured" here is intended to mean "subtly complex"

Comment: Yes, but perplexity is a property of the person considering the concept, not the concept itself.

Comment: @ArthurB - I thought that too, but the alternate definition seems to apply to the thing, not the person, as in "the perplexities of international relations" (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/perplexity).

Answer (score 2):

Consider [***subtlety***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subtlety#English). The first definition for [*subtle*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subtle) fits reasonably well:

> 1. Hard to grasp; not obvious or easily understood; barely noticeable.
>      *The difference is subtle, but you can hear it if you listen carefully.*
> 2. *(of a thing)* Cleverly contrived.
> 3. *(of a person or animal)* Cunning, skillful.
> 4. Insidious.
> 5. Tenuous; rarefied; of low density or thin consistency.

A problem which is *subtle* is likely to not look terribly complex on the surface, but ***subtleties*** will likely cause those complexities to surface upon deeper examination. They may make reasoning about the problem much more complicated, especially since they complicate the mental model in *subtle* ways.

This also seems to fit your domain relatively well, as I have heard the word used in PL theory before, and I’ve absolutely used it myself in CS and programming contexts.

It also works in both the way you describe—used as an uncountable noun like “inscrutability”—or to refer to the problem itself—used as a countable noun, usually plural as “subtleties”.

Answer (score 1):

**Recondite** might be what you're looking for, but (appropriately) it's not a word that most people will know.  From Wiktionary:

recondite ‎(comparative more recondite, superlative most recondite)

```
1. (of areas of study and literature) Difficult, obscure; particularly:
    1. Abstruse, profound, difficult to grasp
    2. Esoteric, little known; secret  
    3. (of writers) Deliberately obscure; employing abstruse or esoteric allusions or references  
    4. (of scholars) Learnèd, having mastery over one's field, including its esoteric minutiæ
```

Answer (score 0):

**conundrum**

> A confusing or difficult problem or question.

Comment: Conundrum is good, but I'm looking for a noun describing a property of the problem, not the problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

***Nebulous*** (vague, indistinct, formless, ill-defined - OED), or

***vague*** (couched in general or indefinite terms; not definitely or precisely expressed; deficient in details or particulars; indefinite, indistinct; not precise or exact - OED), perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 words I like for this. One is **precarious**:

> Dependent on circumstances beyond one's control; uncertain; unstable; insecure:

(http://www.dictionary.com/browse/precarious)

Thus, a precarious situation has the possibility of being a tricky one, or, depending on circumstances, though these circumstances are out of your control, it could end up being just fine.

The other is **situation**

The main defintion is

> The combination of circumstances at a given moment; a state of affairs.

But a colloquial definition is to use the word without a qualifier to implicitly mean a tricky situation

> A difficult or unpleasant set of circumstances; a problem.

(https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/situation)

The example wiktionary gives is

*Boss, we've got a **situation** here...*

So the word also can be something tricky or not.